# Celery beat_schedule using wrong timezone

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I am trying to run a daily task as part of my Django web application using celery beat, which calls a function with a date string argument. The beat schedule works fine and calls the function at the right time each day, but the date string inputted to the function is always one day behind. I assume this is because the timezone setting is wrong, but I think I have configured Django and celery correctly so I can't see where the problem is.

Relevant settings in `./settings.py`:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
USE_TZ = True
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
```

My celery config in `./my_project/celery.py`:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


app = Celery('my_project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

# Configure daily tasks
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes `my_task` every day at 10:00am
    'do-my-task': {
        'task': 'tasks.tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=10),
        'args': (timezone.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), ),
    },
}
```

Any ideas why this should be inputting the wrong date string as the argument to `my_task`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django.utils.timezone.now` does not do what you think it does.  [According to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) it will return the time in UTC with the timezone set to UTC.  It will not return the time in `Europe/London` as you want:

> If **`USE_TZ`** is **`True`**, this will be an aware `datetime` representing the current time in UTC. Note that **`now()`** will always return times in UTC regardless of the value of **`TIME_ZONE`**; you can use **`localtime()`** to get the time in the current time zone.

As the docs suggest, use `localtime` instead of `now`.

Comment: Yes tried that out and it's working as expected now, thanks!

Comment: Actually tried that and it is working correctly on my dev server, but still has the same error when deployed on Heroku... have I set the timezone settings correctly?

Comment: That depends--the timezone names are OS-specific.  I don't know if Heroku supports 'Europe/London' as a timezone.

Comment: Worked in the end on Heroku... I guess I just needed a reset to load the latest settings :)